# angularjs not posting to database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a MEAN application set up, however, one of my models is not functioning. For some reason, I am not able to post to my database. Please look over my code below:

**Schema**

```
var GroupSchema = Schema({
    name    : String, 
    posts   : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post"}], 
    user    : {type:String, ref:"User" },
    created : {type:Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Group', GroupSchema);
```

**server (partial)**

```
router.route('/groups')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var group = new Group();
        group.name = req.body.name;
        group.user = req.body.user;
        group.save(function(err) {
            if (err) 
               res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'group created!' });
        });
    }) 
    .get(function(req, res) {
        var current_user = req.user;
        console.log("req: " + req)

        Group.find({ user: current_user._id }).exec(function(err, groups) {
          if (err) throw err;

          // show the admins in the past month
          console.log(groups);
           res.json(groups);
           console.log("current user:" + current_user);
        });
    });
```

**Controller (partial)**

```
myApp.controller('sideNav', function ($http, $scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log) {
    var refreshGroup = function(){
        $http.get('/api/groups').success(function(response) {
            console.log('I got the group data! :D');
            $scope.groups = response;
            $scope.group = "";
        });
    }
    refreshGroup();

    $scope.addGroup = function() {
        //$scope.post.url = parenturl;
        console.log($scope.group._id);

        $http.post('/api/groups', $scope.group).success(function(response){
            refreshGroup();
        });

    };
  });
```

**View (partial)**

```
<div id="creategroup" ng-show="showAddGroup">
<input id="new-group-user" style="display:none !important;" class="hidden form-control" ng-model="group.user" ng-init="group.user='<%= user._id %>'" placeholder="{{group.user}}" value="{{group.user}}">
<md-input-container>
    <label for="input_1">New Group</label>
    <input id="newGroup input_1" style="display:inline !important;" class="ng-pristine form-control" ng-model="group.name" />
</md-input-container>
<md-button style="display:inline !important;" id="theGroupButton" class=" hidden btn btn-primary" ng-click="addGroup()">Add Group</md-button>
```

When I click *add group* I am not getting any erros, however, my two ng-models *user* and *name* are not going through. When I console.log from the controller using *$scope.group._id,* *$scope.group.user* and *$scope.group.name* they both come back undefined.

Is anyone able to see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My observations from your code is following -

1. Initially when you are calling refreshGroup(), it makes your $scope.group set to empty string and this makes the HTML part which is group.user and group.name as undefined.
2. After clicking on add Group, you are getting returned the same undefined value and the same undefined value is now passed to the API and the cycle repeats.

As per my understanding do not set $scope.group to empty string, instead just replace it with the server data such as $scope.group = response.

Also, it's a good practise to initialise the $scope variables with their default values before using them.